# Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I can't figure out why I'm getting an

Cannot read property 'finally' of undefined error here..

```
$scope.saveToDos = function(){
    console.log("Save to do was pressed.")
    var filteredTodos = $scope.todos.filter(function(todo){
        if(todo.edited){
            return todo
        }
    })
    console.log("There are " + filteredTodos.length + " edited todos")
    dataService.saveToDos(filteredTodos)
    .finally($scope.resetTodoState())
}
```

It errors out on the finally line and I'm not sure why. 
The issue can be reproduced cloning Git repo 
https://github.com/Velua/To-Do-List

```
this.saveToDos = function(todos){
        var queue = [];
        todos.forEach(function(todo){
            var request;
            if(!todo._id){
                request = $http.post('/api/todos', todo);
            } else{
                request = $http.put('/api/todos/' + todo._id, todo).then(function(result){
                    todo = result.data.todo;
                    return todo
                })
            }
            queue.push(request);
        })
        $q.all(queue).then(function(results){
            console.log("I saved " + todos.length + " todos!");
        })
    }
```

Thanks!

Comment: What does `dataService.saveToDos` return?

Comment: `finally()` is a reserved keyword (function); part of a try...catch...finally. so without try block, finally will cause such error.

Comment: @KiranShakya That would be true if it were used as a keyword, but it isn't.

Comment: @JJJ it has now been updated

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You aren't returning anything from `saveToDos()`, so the return value is by default `undefined`.

You probably wanted to `return $q.all(...`

Comment: You bloody legend! Thanks a lot!